# JSF 2.0: Passing composite component attribute to inner composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have the following case:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="someValue" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:composite>
    <x:someComponent>
        <span>#{cc.attrs.someValue}</span>
    </x:someComponent>
</cc:composite>
```

So inside my composite component I am calling some other composite component and trying to pass the parameter given to the "master" composite component to the inner composite component.

This fails, because inside `x:someComponent` tags the `cc` implicit object seems to refer to this `x:someComponent` instead.

A workaround is to create a temporary field for the `x:someComponent` so this can be achieved as:

```
<x:someComponent passthroughField="#{cc.attrs.someValue}">
    <span>#{cc.attrs.passthroughField}</span>
</x:someComponent>
```

However that's very ugly and unconvenient.

Any other ways around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to hack around this is to use `ui:param` as in:

```
<ui:param name="foo" value="cc.attrs.someValue" />
<x:someComponent>
    <span>#{foo}</span>
</x:someComponent>
```

See more in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585755/jsf-creating-aliases-for-properties-in-backing-bean).

Comment: I've been using this now. It works, so picking my own answer as accepted :)