# JSF: Creating aliases for properties in backing bean

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am referring to pretty deep object hierarchies with pretty cryptic names in EL as in `#{myBean.configBaseStack.excludeMethodFromAccounting.method.TimeoutBehaviorEnabled}`.

I would like to point to this very same property through an alias like in:

```
<x:alias name="m" value="#{myBean.configBaseStack.excludeMethodFromAccounting.method" />
<h:inputText value="#{m.TimeoutBehaviorEnabled}" />
```

I guess one way to accomplish this would be to create these aliases in the backing bean, but I'd rather leave that to the template.

How to accomplish this in template/facelet level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use `<ui:param>` to accomplish this:

```
<ui:param name="m" value="#{myBean.configBaseStack.excludeMethodFromAccounting.method}"/>
```

Then you can use it like this on the same page:

```
<h:inputText value="#{m.TimeoutBehaviorEnabled}" />
```

Comment: I knew this was simple. I checked `f:param` and `f:attribute` but didn't realize there was this :) Seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Read section "<c:set> vs <ui:param>" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the JSTL-equivalent [set](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html) tag for this (using the `var` and `value` attributes).

Comment: That would be possible, but it would lock the relation. Using `ui:param` as Shervin suggests allows using properties more flexibly. Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

For all i know aliasing is not not supported in jsf, using the standard components that is.